# Understanding - "$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$check->Nmsgs}",0);"

Tags: php

I am tring to learn about the imap function, and I am struggling to understand:

```
$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$check->Nmsgs}",0);
```

In particular `$mbox,"1:{$check->Nmsgs}",0`

PHP manual says it uses the  **X:Y syntax.**

But I just cant get my head around it.

Please can anyone assist.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the docs, which you should definitely start reading now:

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

And follow this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing